# javax.naming.NoInitialContextException in simple jms app

Tags: java, jboss, jms, publish-subscribe

```
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.jms.*;
import javax.naming.*;

public class TopicConsumer implements MessageListener  {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws JMSException, NamingException {
        System.out.println("------>STARTING JMS TopicConsumer<----");

        Context context= TopicConsumer.getInitialContext();

        System.out.println(">>>1<<<");
        TopicConnectionFactory topicConnectionFactory= (TopicConnectionFactory)context.lookup("ConnectionFactory");
        System.out.println(">>>2<<<");
        Topic topic= (Topic) context.lookup("Topic/AKSHAY");
        System.out.println(">>>3<<<");
        TopicConnection topicConnection= topicConnectionFactory.createTopicConnection();
        System.out.println(">>>4<<<");
        TopicSession topicSession= topicConnection.createTopicSession(false,TopicSession.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        System.out.println(">>>5<<<");
        topicSession.createSubscriber(topic).setMessageListener(new TopicConsumer());
        System.out.println(">>>6<<<");
        topicConnection.start();
                System.out.println("------>Énding JMS TopicConsumer<----");
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        try {
            System.out.println(">>>on msg<<<");
            System.out.println("Incoming message is"+((TextMessage)message).getText());
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static Context getInitialContext() throws JMSException, NamingException{
        System.out.println(">>>7<<<");
        Properties props=new Properties();
        System.out.println(">>>8<<<");
        props.setProperty("java.naming.factory.initial","org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory");
        System.out.println(">>>9<<<");
        props.setProperty("java.naming.factory.url.pkgs","org.jboss.naming");
        System.out.println(">>>10<<<");
        props.setProperty("java.naming.provider.url","localhost:1099");
        System.out.println(">>>11<<<");
        Context context= new InitialContext();
        System.out.println(">>>12<<<");
        return context;

    }

}
```

> Exception in thread "main" javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify    class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
>           at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(Unknown Source)
>           at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(Unknown Source)
>           at javax.naming.InitialContext.getURLOrDefaultInitCtx(Unknown Source)
>           at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(Unknown Source)
>           at TopicProducer.main(TopicProducer.java:19)

I am new for Jms.My code is like this.Exception is Naming Exception:
I seem to have a problem in setting up the JNDI or classpath.
I have included the following JMS.jar file
Problem in classpath or JNDI ...?
Using Eclipse Juno Jboss 5.0 and JDK 1.7

Comment: Add the stacktrace please

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot to include the properties while creating the context.

So instead of

```
Context context= new InitialContext();
```

try

```
Context context= new InitialContext(properties);
```

Comment: Does your program run now? Do you need anymore help?